# Loop over JSON elements in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a long JSON string, and I want to find matching names in other elements. Something like in which other elements appears "Bob" and "John" names or "Jacob" and "Max". I was thinking to loop first element names and try to find them in other elements  and continue doing it until very last element. The matching names arrays, according on length sort in to different lists. However, I don't know to accomplish this in python. Please help me.
The JSON looks like fallowing:

```json
    [
        {
            "group": 01,
            "names": [
                "Bob",
                "John",
                "Alex",
                "Jacob",
                "Theo",
                "Thomas",
                "Max"
            ],
            "status": "none"
        },
        {
            "group": 02,
            "names": [
                "Martin",
                "Bryan",
                "Alex",
                "Adam",
                "Arlo",
                "Luca",
                "Ellis"
            ],
            "status": "In Progress"
        },
        {
            "group": 03,
            "names": [
                "Alex",
                "John",
                "Emma",
                "Toby",
                "Ryan",
                "Leon",
                "Blake"
            ],
            "status": "Completed"
        },
        {
            "group": 04,
            "names": [
                "John",
                "Martin",
                "Liam",
                "Felix",
                "Finn",
                "Ollie",
                "Elliot"
            ],
            "status": "In Progress"
        },
        {
            "group": 05,
            "names": [
                "Luke",
                "Emma",
                "Alex",
                "Arlo",
                "Finn",
                "Bob",
                "Theo"
            ],
            "status": "In Progress"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. I see you have tagged this question with `json`. Have you looked at the `json` module?

Answer (score 0):

This example will use the `json` module to load the Json data from a file and then filter the items to only those which contain "Bob" and "John":

```py
import json

with open("data.json", "r") as f_in:
    data = json.load(f_in)

# find elements which contain "Bob" and "John"

out = []
for d in data:
    if "Bob" in d["names"] and "John" in d["names"]:
        out.append(d)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "group": 1,
        "names": ["Bob", "John", "Alex", "Jacob", "Theo", "Thomas", "Max"],
        "status": "none",
    }
]
```